# How to call a method when there's a string for the user input? (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, math

What the title says: I'm writing a program where it calculates and shows the sum of the digits in a number (Ex: 3782 sum = 20).

However, I'm having trouble calling the method I used to calculate it back to the main method - it gives me a "java: cannot find symbol" error.
I need to use a `String` for this, and cannot use `int` for my values.

Here's my code:

```
public class digitSum {
  //MAIN
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a whole number: ");
        String num = input.nextLine();

        //SUM METHOD CALL
           // This is the method call I'm having trouble with.
        printResult(numSum(sum));



    }

  //SUM METHOD
    static void numSum(int i, String num, int sum) {
        for (i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
            char a = num.charAt(0);
            char b = num.charAt(i);
            sum = a + b;
        }
        System.out.println("The digit-sum of" +num+ " is: " +sum);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: What "symbol" cannot be found?

Comment: The variable for sum is the symbol that can't be found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've never defined `sum` variable:

```
int sum = 0;
printResult(numSum(0, num, sum));
```

Or even better - why passing accumulator and counter to the function if it's not recursive?

```
static void numSum(String num) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
        char a = num.charAt(0);
        char b = num.charAt(i);
        sum = a + b;
    }
    System.out.println("The digit-sum of" +num+ " is: " +sum);
    return;
}
```

Then invoke it by simply calling `numSum(num)`.

P.S.: You also need to have `printResult` defined (or not - `numSum` is printing the result).

@chrylis -on strike- notices, that printing the result of your calculation in the caller would be even better:

```
static int numSum(String num) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
        char a = num.charAt(0);
        char b = num.charAt(i);
        sum = a + b;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

And in the `main` method:

```
System.out.println(numSum(num));
```

Comment: numSun also takes int, String, int

Comment: @redFIVE yeah, just noticed, right when clicked "answer", thanks;>

Comment: According to the code in the original question, method `printResult` has a method parameter, but method `numSum` returns `void`. What am I missing?

Comment: @Abra sorry, but I don't see it. Where does it say, that the lambda has to be passed? Also as the last note I added, that `printResult` can be dropped.

Comment: Better still, *return* the sum and print it in the caller.

Comment: Thanks, you guys!! The program's working. c:
I just need to debug it to figure out why it's giving my 101 instead of 20 for the input 3872 but hopefully I can get it in 2 hours.
Stay healthy and happy programming!